# How to check the checkboxes using the Selenium Java WebDriver?

Tags: java, html, selenium, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to figure out a way to check the checkboxes in the table grid. Usually they are defined as type='checkbox'. So I'm finding it difficult to implement using the webDriver to check the checkboxes since they are in the  tags.

A sample HTML code is given below.

```html
<tbody id="gridview-2345-body">
 <tr id="gridview-2345-record-/DNA/Study1_HS.xml" class="x4-grid-row x4-grid-data-row x4-grid-row-selected" data-boundview="gridview-1270" role="row">
  <td id="ext4-ext-gen1234" class="x4-grid-cell x4-grid-td" role="gridcell">
   <div class="x4-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;" unselectable="on">
    <div class="x4-grid-row-checker"/>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td id="ext4-ext-1235" class="x4-grid-cell x4-grid-td" role="gridcell">
   <div class="x4-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;" unselectable="on">
    <span id="ext4-icon1568" class="fa fa-file-code-o labkey-file-icon"/>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td id="ext4-ext-gen1236" class="x4-grid-cell x4-grid-td" role="gridcell">
   <div class="x4-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;" unselectable="on">
    <div width="100%" height="16px">
     <div style="float: left;"/>
     <div style="padding-left: 8px; white-space:normal !important;">
      <span style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;">Study1_HS.xml</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried using 'contains' in the xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'Study1_HS.xml')]/td[1]/div/div")).click();
```

Comment: Its check, but i saw a few other posts using click(), so i tried using the click(). Once I check the checkbox in the table row. I need to click another button. But as of now, i'm just trying out a way to check the checkbox.

Comment: Is there any exception occurred or something else when you are using `.click()`..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur - It gives this Message "ERROR: Unable to find element: xpath=//*[contains(@id, 'Study1_HS.xml')]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html"

Comment: Try to use this `$x("/")` in your browser console to find the error in that xpath. That sample HTML code it's missing **<table>** tag. Without that tag, chrome not render your **tr** tag

Comment: @shockwave: Can you please tell me whether there is any change in the HTML code if the checkbox is checked?

Comment: Just the class attribute changes in the <tr> tag. from 

class="x4-grid-row x4-grid-data-row"
  *****to ******
class="x4-grid-row x4-grid-data-row x4-grid-row-selected x4-grid-row-focused"

Comment: @jpozorio - Yes I checked the path "//*[contains(@id, 'Study1_HS.xml')]/td[1]/div/div" It highlights the exact checkbox which is a div tag

Comment: Is it possible for you to give the website address to validate this scenario? Because, I need to check the xpath when atleast one checkbox is selected.

Comment: @k.s.Karthik - I wish I could give, but its on Localhost. However here is the xpath generated by chrome when the checkbox is checked
first checkbox  -     //*[@id="ext4-ext-gen1234"]/div/div
******* second checkbox   -    //*[@id="ext4-ext-gen1239"]/div/div

Comment: You try to use `wait()`? Sometimes I get this error because the element was not displayed yet when I call an action

Comment: As we are using `contains` there might be a chance that there are more than 1 element is identified. So please use the complete `id` in the xpath like `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[@id='gridview-2345-record-/DNA/Study1_HS.xml']`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used 'preceding' in the xpath to make it work

```
//span[text()='Study1_HS.xml']/preceding::td/div/div[@class='x4-grid-row-checker']
```

http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/b1d50008dd4be8ab7545548c4b8238f5

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering... since the TR contains the class change when the checkbox is checked, maybe clicking the TR will trigger the check. Try this and see.

```
String searchText = "Study1_HS.xml";
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for (WebElement row : rows)
{
    if (row.getText().contains(searchText))
    {
        row.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If that doesn't work... right-click on the checkbox and inspect element. What element comes up?